How boolean property from object is shown both true and false in console?
I am building an object. He has a boolean property isRelevant that should be true. But it is both showing true and false in console:

I have read it may be due to asynchronous operation but not sure about it.
Any idea on what is going on here?
code :
export function consolidateCertifications(
    gameCertifications: IGameCertification[],
    certifications: Certification[],
): IGameCertification[] {
    return certifications.map(c => {
        const savedGameCertification: IGameCertification | undefined = gameCertifications.find(gc => gc.id === c.id);
        let isCompleted = false;
        let isRelevant = false;

        if (!isNil(savedGameCertification)) {
            isCompleted = savedGameCertification.isCompleted;
            isRelevant = savedGameCertification.isRelevant;
        }
        console.log('isRelevant', isRelevant);

        const returnValue = {
            id: c.id,
            isRelevant: isRelevant,
            name: c.name,
            isCompleted: isCompleted,
            hasSrijRegulatedCountries: c.hasSrijRegulatedCountries,
            certificationData: savedGameCertification?.certificationData,
        };
        console.log(returnValue);
        return returnValue;
    });
}


See explanation under https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#snapshotting_objects

@Ryley38 there is nothing asynchronous in your code, do a console.log of savedGameCertification and check if its causing the issue

Something somewhere (not in the code presented) is changing the value of isRelevant on your returned returnValue object after you've logged it, but before you've expanded it in the console. It may or may not be async. eg even this exhibits the same behaviour: var x = {a:false}; console.log(x); x.a = true;
